# JavaFX Loading Indicator not animated when shown

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

My program takes a some time to load, so while it's loading, I'm displaying a loading window. However, the loading indicator that i put in doesn't rotate when i use .show(), but for some reason will work when using .showAndWait().
I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. Here is the controller that calls the loading window.

```
package FX;

import Utility.*;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Alex on 5/31/2017.
 */
public class WindowController {

@FXML private TextField startBox;
@FXML private Button genButton;
@FXML private ComboBox startPage;
@FXML private ComboBox endPage;
@FXML private GridPane grid;
private Stage loadingStage;
private Scene loadingScene;

private Graph graph;

@FXML
public void initialize()throws IOException{
    AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LoadingScreen.fxml"));

    loadingScene = new Scene(pane);
    loadingStage = new Stage();
    loadingStage.setTitle("Loading");
    loadingStage.setResizable(false);
    loadingStage.setScene(loadingScene);
    //loadingStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
}

@FXML
public void GeneratePressed() throws IOException{
    loadingStage.show();
    String page = startBox.getText();
    graph = new Graph(page);

    ObservableList<String> list = graph.getNamesList();
    startPage.setItems(list);
    endPage.setItems(list);
    loadingStage.close();
}

@FXML void FindPathPressed(){

}

public void dislayLoading(){

}

}
```

The window is called in GeneratePressed(), and is created in the initializer.
Also, I tried to get the windows navbar to not apear by using

```
loadingStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
```

but that seems to crash the program.

Finaly, here is my fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="180.0" maxWidth="250.0" minHeight="180.0" 
minWidth="250.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="250.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="FX.LoadingScreenController">
   <children>
      <Text layoutX="87.0" layoutY="52.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" 
strokeWidth="0.0" text="Loading" textAlignment="CENTER">
     <font>
        <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
     </font>
  </Text>
  <ProgressIndicator fx:id="load" layoutX="87.0" layoutY="74.0" 
prefHeight="72.0" prefWidth="76.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: `GeneratePressed` is presumably an event handler method, so it is invoked on the FX Application Thread. So it runs to completion before the FX Application Thread can do anything else. So, either there is not enough time between `loadingStage.show()` and `loadingStage.close()` for you to actually see the window, or you block the FX Application Thread and prevent it from rendering the UI, meaning you can't see the window. If you have long-running code you need to run it on a background thread. See the [API docs for `Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this for loading my fxmls. You need no fxml or only one with a single pane on it.

```
/*
 * Loader for custom FXML on ScrollPane
 * You doesn't need the parameter, you can replace it
 * with your own fix path if you only load one view.
 */
Task<Parent> loadFXML(String path) {
    //Loader Task
    Task<Parent> createMainScene = new Task<Parent>() {
        @Override
        public Parent call() {
            //Update Message
            updateMessage("Loading...");

            //Pane with FXML
            Pane pane = null;

            try {
                // FXML loader
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

                // Set path to PARAMETERLISTE.fxml
                loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(path));

                // Set load fxml to Pane
                pane = (Pane) loader.load();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error. Grund: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            //Return Pane
            return pane;
        }
    };

    //ProgressBar
    ProgressBar pBar = new ProgressBar();
    //Load Value from Task
    pBar.progressProperty().bind(createMainScene.progressProperty());
    //Set PrefWidth
    pBar.setPrefWidth(250);
    //New Loading Label
    Label statusLabel = new Label();
    //Get Text
    statusLabel.textProperty().bind(createMainScene.messageProperty());
    //Set Style to Label
    statusLabel.setStyle("-fx-font: 24 arial;");

    //Layout
    VBox root = new VBox(statusLabel, pBar);
    //SetFill Width TRUE
    root.setFillWidth(true);
    //Center Items
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    //Set Layout to ScrollPane
    scrollpane.setContent(root);

    //Display loaded FXML onSucceed
    createMainScene.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
        scrollpane.setContent(createMainScene.getValue());
    });

    //Start Thread
    new Thread(createMainScene).start();

    return createMainScene;
}
```

Maybe this helps you. You can set custom progress with:

```
updateProgress([YOUR PROGRESS], [MAX VALUE]);
```

To access it from a other methode use:

```
    //Load yFXML
    Task<Parent> task = loadFXML("/YOURFXML.fxml");
    //Set on Succeeded
    task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent arg0) {
            //Do your Stuff

            //Set Scrollpane to new FXML
            scrollpane.setContent(task.getValue());
        }
    });
```

You need this setOnSucceeded methode because your java is running further if you doesn't wait. May this helps